# Increase spacing between 2 bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My web page has a list of 5 DJs in a row. I'm trying to place advertisements on the the right side of it.

Here is how it looks without ads

[image: Here is how it looks without ads]

After placing the ads it looks like this

[image: After placing the ads it looks like this]

How can I increase the spacing between 2 consecutive columns? I think it can be done via changing the gutter-width and downloading a customized bootstrap file but I think there would be an easier only CSS way to handle this.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 3 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 4 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 5 -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 3 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 4 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- DJ 5 -->
            </div>
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="edm-sides" align="right">
            <!-- ad-1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="edm-sides" align="right">
            <!-- ad-2 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: changing the gutter-width and downloading the custom bootstrap is the easiest way to do it. There is some calculation involved based on gutter-width and number of cols. That way the width and margin of each col is calculated. I believe it is paddding-left and padding-right = @gutter-width/2 and width = 100/@cols. you will need to change only the paddings

You will then need to do similar calculations for maintaining the responsiveness (I think, though I am not sure). I will advice you to download the customized bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the width using CSS works

```
.dj-md-2{
    width:18%;
}
```

Add `dj-md-2` to the div `<div class="col-md-2 dj-md-2">`